# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (RuntimeError: The connection cannot be reused in the forked process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, cancan

Hi I am using `CANCAN Gem` for user roles and

```
database ->oracle
oracle adaptor - > oracle_enhanced_adaptor 1.4.1
ruby 1.9.3
rails 3.2.16
web server -> unicorn
```

when i refresh broser after some time ( 2 or 3 minutes) . It gives us `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (RuntimeError: The connection cannot be reused in the forked process.`:

Anyone help me

Comment: This is running under which webserver? (unicorn, webrick, passenger, puma...) Depending on your webserver, you might need to reconnect after forking.

Comment: unicorn web server i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a answer from google community

```
dbconfig = ActiveRecord::Base.remove_connection
child_pid = fork do
# establish new db connection for forked child
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)
   # do stuff...
end
# re-establish db connection
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(dbconfig)
# detach the process so we don't wait for it
Process.detach(child_pid)
```

in `environment.rb` file and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your unicorn.rb file

```
#config/unicorn.rb
after_fork do |server, worker|
  defined?(ActiveRecord::Base) && ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

and you can run the server with the command `unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb` to use the config.

Comment: i added a new file unicorn.rb in config folder and paste your code after run server like this rails s unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb          it gives us  `<top (required)>': undefined method `after_fork' for main:Object (NoMethodError)